# Angle of intersection of the given curves.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, circles, curves

What is the angle of intersection of $$[|\sin x| + |\cos x|]$$ And the curve $$ x^2 + y^2 = 5 $$ where $[n]$ denotes greatest integer function.
This is a homework question. I have tried to find the intersection of these two curves but i am unable to do so. In the solution booklet provided , the first curve has been changed to $y = 1 $ without any explanation. Can anyone please explain me this ?

Comment: For $0\le x\le\dfrac\pi2,|\sin x|+|\cos x|=\sin x+\cos x=\sqrt2\sin\left(x+\dfrac\pi4\right)$

and $\dfrac\pi4\le x+\dfrac\pi4\le\dfrac\pi2+\dfrac\pi4$   $\implies\sqrt2\sin\left(x+\dfrac\pi4\right)\ge1$

 $\implies[|\sin x|+|\cos x|]=1$ for $0\le x\le\dfrac\pi2$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Ok. Thanks. Post this as an answer and i will mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** From the above hint it is proved that **[|sinx+cosx|]=1**...(eq i)

Again,if we find the **local extremum** for the above equation(eq i) [0<=x<=(pi/2)],
we get the **maximum value as (root 2)=1.414(approx), minimum value=1**.

So,in this way we can also get that **[|sinx+cosx|]=1**.

Thus **y=[|sinx|+|cosx|]=1**

**2)** Now, find the point of intersection between **y=1** & **x^2+y^2=5**

**3)** Since one of the curve is a **circle**, find the **equation of the tangent to the circle (at the point of intersection of the straight line & the circle)**.

**4)** Find the **slopes of the tangent & the straight line**.

**5)** Now find the angle between them by using the equation **[|(a-b)/(1+ab)|]**  (where a & b are the slopes of the tangent & straight line respectively)